# Counting values from diffrent columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm working with a pandas dataframe that has some columns like these:

```
Col1     Col2    Col3    Col4
Yes      No      Perhaps Not sure
Perhaps  Yes             No
No               Yes
```

I'm trying to count the values of each column and then adding them together to get the total counts of that values. 
however, It's not working with columns that don't have all the values like **Col4** is missing Yes and perhaps

What is the best way to approach this problem?

Comment: You could convert your table to long format (i.e. a table with only one column) and call  the pandas function DataFrame.value_counts(). This function can handle NA's and you would receive the total counts for each value.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Create the DataFrame.
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Col1': ['Yes', 'Perhaps', 'No'],
    'Col2': ['No', 'Yes', np.nan],
    'Col3': ['Perhaps', np.nan, 'Yes'],
    'Col4': ['Not sure', 'No', np.nan],
})

counts = (
    df
    .apply(pd.Series.value_counts)  # 1. Count the number of occurrences of each value in each column.
    .sum(axis=1)                    # 2. Sum the counts across columns.
    .astype(int)                    # 3. Convert to integer.
    .sort_values(ascending=False)   # 4. Sort the counts in descending order.
    .to_frame('counts')             # 5. Convert to a named DataFrame.
)

> print(counts)

        counts
No           3
Yes          3
Perhaps      2
Not sure     1
```

*Number 3–5 is optional formatting.*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).